# Bootstrapping/Monte Carlo Simulation in R

Tags: r, bootstrap-4, montecarlo

I am trying to follow this test:

[image: Stat test]

Suppose I have the following data:

```
set.seed(123)

active_MJO   <-c(6L, 2L, 11L, 20L, 62L, 15L, 2L, 51L, 58L, 100L, 45L, 44L, 49L, 
                86L, 28L, 1L, 1L, 40L, 79L, 99L, 86L, 50L, 9L, 78L, 45L, 100L, 
                77L, 44L, 45L, 93L)

inactive_MJO <-c(83L, 170L, 26L, 66L, 156L, 40L, 29L, 72L, 109L, 169L, 153L, 
               136L, 169L, 133L, 153L, 13L, 24L, 148L, 121L, 80L, 125L, 21L, 
               135L, 155L, 161L, 171L, 124L, 177L, 167L, 162L)
```

I dont know how to implement the above test in R.

I have tried the following but I am not sure if this is correct.

```
sig.test <- function (x){
a <- sample(active_MJO)
b <- sample(inactive_MJO)
sum(a > b)
}

runs <- 1000
sim <- sum(replicate(runs,sig.test(dat))+1)/(runs+1)
```

I think the above is not correct. Where can I put the 950/1000 condition?

Apologies, I am new to bootstrapping/Monte Carlo test.

I'll appreciate any help on this.

Sincerely,
Lyndz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it's important to note that they are sampling 30 frequency *pairs*. Since it's bootstrapping, those samples will be with replacement.

Then they compare the average active to average inactive. This is equivalent to:

1. comparing the sum of the active against the sum of the inactive from the 30 pairs, or
2. comparing the sum of the differences within each of the 30 pairs to zero.

They repeat the process 1000 times then compare the results of the 1000 comparisons to 950.

The following code performs #2:

```
set.seed(123)

active_MJO   <-c(6L, 2L, 11L, 20L, 62L, 15L, 2L, 51L, 58L, 100L, 45L, 44L, 49L, 
                 86L, 28L, 1L, 1L, 40L, 79L, 99L, 86L, 50L, 9L, 78L, 45L, 100L, 
                 77L, 44L, 45L, 93L)
inactive_MJO <-c(83L, 170L, 26L, 66L, 156L, 40L, 29L, 72L, 109L, 169L, 153L, 
                 136L, 169L, 133L, 153L, 13L, 24L, 148L, 121L, 80L, 125L, 21L, 
                 135L, 155L, 161L, 171L, 124L, 177L, 167L, 162L)

diff_MJO <- active_MJO - inactive_MJO
sim <- sum(replicate(1e3, sum(sample(diff_MJO, 30, replace = TRUE)) > 0))

> sim
[1] 0
```

In this case, none of the 1000 replications resulted in an average `active_MJO` that was greater than the average `inactive_MJO`. This is unsurprising after plotting the histogram of sums of bootstrapped differences:

```
diff_MJO <- replicate(1e5, sum(sample(diff_MJO, 30, replace = TRUE)))
hist(diff_MJO)
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for this answer!! I was trying to interpret the test. I thought it was similar to the bootrap t-test from Efron and Tibshirani's book. Will try this on the real data